# How to close rich:popupPanel on press of Esc key?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

How  to  close rich:popupPanel on press of Esc key?

how to  make it  work  for  hotkeys in  keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

I would try the following:

```
   <rich:hotKey key="Esc">
        <rich:componentControl target="popupId" operation="hide" />
   </rich:hotKey>

   <rich:popupPanel id="popupId">
      ...
   </rich:popupPanel>
```

More info in [`<rich:hotKey>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functionality_extension.html#sect-Component_Reference-Functionality_extension-richhotKey) documentation.